# Style Switcher PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I tried to make a style switcher from my Admin Panel, I added in:

**index.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php echo($thestyle);?>.css" >
<?php
$thestyle = $_GET['set'];
if ($thestyle == "style1")
    {
    $thestyle = "style2";
    }
else
    {
    $thestyle = "style1";
    }
?>
```

And in **dashboard.php** from Admin Panel

```
<a href="index.php?set=style1">Style Sheet One</a>
<a href="index.php?set=style2">Style Sheet Two</a>
```

This changes the stylesheet on my site, but how can I make it so the changes are stored in MySQL too?

this code is only for language in administration panel, not for users, i want make an simple 0-1 style in mysql

Comment: Save the value in your DB and read it on the site?

Comment: It's better to use cookies.

Comment: The best way is in the user profile you have the selection of style and when he save the profile you put the style chosen in DB. Or you can verify if the user have a style chosen on DB if not when he chose you save.

Comment: This is only for me, not for user... this switcher is only for administration panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to make a MySQL table for site preferences or something that would store key-value pairs. Then you can update the row whose key is "style" and set the value to 1 or 2.

My concern is that it's a bit strange to have the preference be global and be able to be set like this. It seems like it would make more sense to either:

1. Store this preference as part of your users table using a similar method to what I described above
2. Store this preference in a cookie.

I'd do something along the lines of this:

#### Storing values to a cookie

```
function updateStylePreference($style) {
    $_COOKIE['stylePref'] = $style;
}
```

#### Retrieving values from a cookie

```
function getStylePreference() {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['stylePref'])) {
        return $_COOKIE['stylePref'];
    }

    else {
        // set a default
        updateStylePreference('style1');
        return 'style1';
    }
}
```

Since you said you only need this for yourself, why not a text file (if you're opposed to cookies)?

#### Writing values to a text file

```
    function updateStylePreference($style) {
        file_put_contents("stylepref.txt", $style);
    }

### Retrieving values from a text file
    function getStylePreference() {
        return file_get_contents("stylepref.txt");
    }
```

I really recommend cookies here though.

Comment: you can give me an demo? tnx

Comment: added a basic example of using cookies - try it out and post what you tried and problems you had for more help.

Comment: I need this action only for me in administration panel not for users

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessions, cookies or db.

Very scraped example of how it could work with sessions

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['style'])){
  $_SESSION['style'] = "style1";
}

if(isset($_GET['set'])){
  $_SESSION['style'] = $_GET['set'];
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php echo $_SESSION['style']; ?>.css" >
```

Or as i read now, you'll need to do it in db, then just make a sql like, after the link is clicked:

```
UPDATE table SET style='$variable' WHERE someid = id
```

Comment: I need only for me not for users.. an simple in mysql 0 - 1 select

Comment: Then just do like this: UPDATE table SET style='style1' WHERE id = 1 and likewise with style 2: UPDATE table SET style='style2' WHERE id = 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch a theme, you have tu update in database or session or cookies the value of current style theme.
So next time you read the value in memory to load you current chosen theme

Comment: no with session or cookies... with value to 1 or 2 in mysql... i have style1.css and style2.css